# How do I center a <div>?

Tags: css, alignment, center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to center DIV in DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-div-in-div)

I want to center a `<div>` (I'm new to HTML5 and the `<center>` tag is no more), and by all means avoid using a table. This is what I've got as CSS for the `<div>` in question so far:

```
#roundedcorner {
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-image: url(file:///Macintosh%20HD/Users/julesmazur/Desktop/TAN3.0/Photos/bodydivbg.png);
    width: 960px;
    left: 50%;
    font-family: Ubuntu;
}
```

(for anyone curious, Ubuntu courtesy of Google Web Fonts).

Comment: http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/csslayout.html

Comment: I usually refer to this page when I need to center something: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score 7):

The typical trick is `margin: auto`.  It'll center it inside what-ever it's in.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kTDZR/)

---

Besides that I have a few comments on your code (since you're a beginner).

- `left: 50%;` does nothing unless you change the position style, e.g.,  `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;`
- The container the `div` is in needs to be larger than it -- otherwise centering it really doesn't mean anything.  This is because styles like `margin: auto` are relative to the parent container, i.e., it needs space.
- For Google Web Fonts, make sure you have your `@font-face` with it.  Also, use alternatives.  Not all browsers support web fonts, and the more control you have: the better.  An example would be `font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, Sans;`, ordered from most preferred to most likely backups.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `left`. This will create a gab in the page on the left side. Instead, use `margin: 0 auto`.

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:960px">I'm centered.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center DOM elements that are absolutely positioned (horizontally and vertically) by using:

```
div {
    position    : absolute;
    width       : 960px;
    height      : 500px;
    left        : 50%;
    top         : 50%;
    margin-top  : -250px;
    margin-left : -480px;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KBHjT/

Answer (score -5):

```
<center><div></div></center>
```

try that

Comment: The OP says HTML5.  The `<center>` element is not allowed in HTML5, which is why you're getting down votes.

Comment: `This tag has been deprecated in HTML 4`. *Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/center*